# Implementing multiple functions in a spelling program in c returns all the words misspelled. in cs50 pset5 speller

Tags: c, cs50

The code implements these functions:

- `check()`: check if the word entered is in the dictionary file,
- `load()`: loads the entire dictionary into a hash table,
- `hash()`: hashes a word,
- `size()`: returns the size of the entire dictionary and
- `unload()`: free all the memory used in `load()`.

The problem is that the function `load()` only loads the first word from the file dictionary into the hash table.

Here is the malfunctioning function

```
// Represents a node in a hash table. length being the largest word in the dictionary
typedef struct node {
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
} node;

// Number of hashes in hash table represent the alphabet
const unsigned int N = 26;
// a count variable to pass to the size function
int count = 0;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary) {
    int b = 0;
    char *c = malloc((LENGTH + 1) * sizeof(char));
    FILE *f = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    while (fscanf(f, "%s", c) != EOF) {
        // b is the hash number 
        b = hash(c);
        if (table[b] == NULL) {
            node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
            if (n == NULL) {
                return false;
            }
            strcpy(n->word, c);
            n->next = NULL;

            table[b] = n;
            count++;
            return true;
        } else
        if (table[b] != NULL) {
            node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
            if (n == NULL) {
                return false;
            }

            strcpy(n->word, c);
            n->next = table[b];
            table[b] = n;
            count++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: After creating the first node, you `return true`, thereby breaking the input loop. Instead, only return false when you encounter an error, otherwise return true at the end, after closing the file.

Comment: Do you realise that the code inside `if (table[b] == NULL) {...}` and `else if (table[b] != NULL) {...}` does **exactly the same** ?

Comment: You can simplify adding the node to the table. The logic of the if and else are exactly the same. Keep the code from the else since you need this line: `n->next = table[b];`. `while(fscanf(f, "%s", c) == 1)` is a better loop condition. It is more general and will be false if nothing is read for whatever reason.

Comment: I deleted the return true statement as it ushered me out of the loop and it worked. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the function always returns `true` after inserting the first word into the hash table. Among other problems, you forget to free `c` and to close `f`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

node *table[N];
int count;

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary) {
    char buf[LENGTH + 1];
    FILE *f = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (f == NULL)
        return false;

    // problem: how to prevent `fscanf` from storing too many characters to buf?
    while (fscanf(f, "%s", buf) == 1) {
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL) {
            fclose(f);
            return false;
        }
        strcpy(n->word, buf);
        // b is the hash number 
        int b = hash(buf);
        n->next = table[n];
        table[b] = n;
        count++;
    }
    fclose(f);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that did it for me.